# Probability of finding a ball in an urn

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

There are 5 urns. You and one of your friends A each have a ball.  A selects one of the urns randomly and puts their ball in, and after they are done, you do the same, selecting a random urn and putting your ball into it (possibly the same urn as the one A chose). Another friend B then randomly selects one of the urns. What is the probability that B does not find any balls in the urn that they selected?

I tried to use complementary counting to find the probability, and subtract from 1 the probability that B does find at least one ball in the urn that they select. There is a $(1/5)^2$ chance that you and $A$ put both your balls in the same urn, and a $1/5$ chance that B will select that urn, for a probability of $(1/5)^3$. However, I am unsure on how to calculate the probability when the balls are placed in different urns.

Comment: The reason that you went off the rails is because you haven't been **stretching your intuition** as you studied Probability Theory.  Attempting to blindly apply formulas is not going to work.  Instead, you must strive to have a deep understanding of how the formulas are derived, so that you can **adjust** your thinking when you are forced to tackle (somewhat) unusual Probability  problems.

Comment: Both you and $A$ have five choices.  There are $5$ ways for both of you to pick the same urn.  Hence, the probability that you and $A$ pick the same urn is $\frac{5}{25} = \frac{1}{5}$.  To put it another way, once $A$ has chosen an urn, the probability that you pick the same urn is $1/5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, A places his ball in Urn-1.

The probabilities are:

- $(1/5)$ that the 2nd ball is also in Urn-1. 
  In this case, the probability of B not finding a ball is $(4/5).$
- $(4/5)$ that the 2nd ball is **not** also in Urn-1. 
  In this case, the probability of B not finding a ball is $(3/5).$

Therefore, the desired overall computation is

$$\left[\frac{1}{5} \times \frac{4}{5}\right] + \left[\frac{4}{5} \times \frac{3}{5}\right].$$